# Is it possible to view an url from my web-browser that requires an HTTP authentication?

Tags: php, http, authentication, get

The question is exactly the title. I have the header and the authorization for the page , but i was just wondering if its possible to view it through a web-browser and not through for example php with an http GET request.

If i hit the page on my browser i get :

```
HTTP Status 401 -

type Status report

message

description This request requires HTTP authentication ()
```

Is there a way to put the header and the authentication code to the browser to open it and view the contents , or this is only handled through a scripting language like php?

Comment: if it's a GET request you should just go to the page in a browser?

Comment: No its not a "page". Its a database or something. But is there another way to view the contents except from a GET request?

Comment: you said it's a "page". but merely going to the url or "page" in the browser should work. did you try it?

Comment: yes i get the error in my question , i just edid it

Comment: that means you need to authenticate somewhere before visiting that page

Comment: this page is viewed through an application that uses an http get request with a proper header and authorization. Is it possible to set up my browser with the proper header and authorization code to view the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can provide HTTP authentication for the user `username` with the password `password` using the following syntax:

```
http://username:password@thesite.com/path/to/page.htm
```

Comment: hmm this is what i was looking for BUT when i am trying to use it with my username:password , i get a message saying that "This page doesnt require authentication. This may be an attempt to trick you" and again shows me the page that i show in my queston above , that this page needs http authentication. Any ideas?

Comment: "This page doesn't require authentication. This page needs HTTP authentication." Sounds like an elaborate joke to me. =\

Comment: so what do i do? i mean i can get the contents with a GET request through php , using the correct http headers but is there a way to view it on my browser?

Comment: When you request a page in your browser, it's exactly the same as doing a GET request with PHP. If your PHP code sets the HTTP authentication headers, it's the same as doing what I showed here in the browser--there's literally no difference. So, if it's not working, then there's something going on here other than HTTP authentication. If you can explain to us what that is, then maybe we can help you do it in the browser--but so far, we don't have enough details to answer that question.